# Questions about keeping Service Worker Push Subscriptions In Sync

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, service-worker, web-push, push-api

I've read the push subscription can get out of sync between the browser and the push service.

I've seen two remediations, both look to be non-standard:

1. [ServiceWorkerGlobalScope.onpushsubscriptionchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API#Handling_premature_subscription_expiration)
2. GCM send response, [mentioned here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web#keeping-the-subscription-up-to-date), [spelled out here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http)

   - *understandably non-standard*

I presume any application should handle both of these points at which a subscription can be identified to be out-of-sync (and any/all).

Questions:

1. In general, are there always just the two areas an application can be made aware of a subscription out-of-sync situation? (1. service worker event 2. push service response) *Seems reasonable, looking for confirmation*.
2. Will the ServiceWorkerGlobalScope.onpushsubscriptionchange event (or some equivalent) make it into the [authoritative standard](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html)?
3. In lieu of a service worker event standard, why not just keep the expected subscription endpoint around (in client-side state) and anytime you query the PushManager for the subscription, check if it is out-of-sync (different than expected)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pushsubscriptionchange` event is documented as part of the [Push API specification](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#the-pushsubscriptionchange-event). That should be considered authoritative, and it mentions there `onpushsubscriptionchange` is [exposed](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#events) as part of `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`.

I don't know offhand whether `pushsubscriptionchange` event is fired in all browsers that support the Push API as of this writing, but I believe the general idea is that it's the (eventual) solution to the use case you describe.